# Incorrect time value to database using datetimepicker input

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, codeigniter, datetimepicker

I get this error when trying to insert time to mysql.

"Incorrect time value .... "

My controller:

```
$data = array(
'branch_open_time'  => date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('time_range_from'))),
'branch_close_time' => date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('time_range_to')))
);
$this->db->insert('branch_user',$data);
$this->db->insert_id();
```

My view and javascript:

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append" style="resize: none;" data-autoclose="true">
                    <label for="open">Waktu Buka</label><br />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input data-format="HH:mm PP" type="text" class="form-control" name="time_range_from" id="time_range_from">
                        <span class="add-on input-group-addon" style="height: 30px">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

<div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append" style="resize: none;" data-autoclose="true">
                    <label for="open">Waktu Tutup</label><br />
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input data-format="HH:mm PP" type="text" class="form-control" name="time_range_to" id="time_range_to">
                        <span class="add-on input-group-addon" style="height: 30px">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker
        ({
            pick12HourFormat: true,
            language: 'en',
            pickDate: false
        });
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker
        ({
            pick12HourFormat: true,
            language: 'en',
            pickDate: false
        });
});
```

add function:

```
function add_location(){
branch_open_time = $("#time_range_from").val();
barnch_close_time = $("#time_range_to").val();
$.ajax
    ({
        url : 'add_location',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data:{
            time_range_from: branch_open_time,
            time_range_to: barnch_close_time
        },
        success: function(data)
        {     
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert('Error data');
        }

    });
}
```

The timepicker are showing properly with 12 hour format and I convert it from H:i:s to strtotime before inserting to database, but it's no working. What did I do wrong?

datetimepicker input:

[image: datetimepicker]

Comment: What is your database field type? varchar or time.

Comment: time. @AHJeebon

Comment: And exactly what time format is being sent from the browser? Is it something like `10:30am` or what?

Comment: Inside the function `add_location(){` add `var` to initialize variable. It will be:
`var branch_open_time = $("#time_range_from").val();`
`var barnch_close_time = $("#time_range_to").val();`

Comment: Have you tried to check to output of `date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('time_range_from')))` and `date("H:i:s",strtotime($this->input->post('time_range_to')))`?

Comment: yes, i edited my question adding the screenshot of the input form @RiggsFolly

Comment: i tried it like you suggested but nothing's changed :( @AHJeebon

Comment: may. Which time is in `time_range_from` is it the one at the top `05:54 PM` or the `05 : 54 : 51    PM` which looks like 4 seperate fields

Comment: **Simple debugging suggestion** amend code to `branch_open_time = $("#time_range_from").val(); alert('branch_open_time = '+branch_open_time);` and the same for `branch_close_time`

Comment: `05 : 54 : 51 PM` appear when i clicked on the addon (the grey part) and then the input text showing `05:54 PM` @RiggsFolly

Comment: it gives me `01:00:00` no matter what time I choose :( @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime('05 : 54 : 51 PM'));
```

Will produce a result of `00:00:00`

However the

```
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime('05:54:51 PM'));
```

or

```
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime('05:54:51PM'));
```

Will produce a result of `17:54:51`

So you need to trim those spaces out of the time either in the javascript or the PHP code before sending that data to the INSERT command

For example

```
$t1 = date('H:i:s', str_replace(' ', '', $this->input->post('time_range_from')));
$t2 = date('H:i:s', str_replace(' ', '', $this->input->post('time_range_to')));
$data = array(
            'branch_open_time'  => $t1,
            'branch_close_time' => $t2
            );
$this->db->insert('branch_user',$data);
$this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but it gives me `05:54:51 PM` in the console log and i still get `01:00:00` after inserting to database :(

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns you are inserting this data into

Answer (score -1):

All things being equal:

Update your code to this:

I added var in front of the variable to establish it as a variable

```
function add_location(){
   var branch_open_time = $("#time_range_from").val();
   var barnch_close_time = $("#time_range_to").val();

   $.ajax({
     url : 'add_location',
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "text",
     data:{
        time_range_from: branch_open_time,
        time_range_to: barnch_close_time
     },
     success: function(data)
     {     
        location.reload();
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
     {
        alert('Error data');
     }

 });
```

}

The spaces in your date is making it invalid before inserting

Use this to remove space from the date to make it a valid one:

```
str_replace(' ','',$date);
```